# Why can't I see the new super galaxy yacht on gta v online whenever I go on my phone I can't find or see it

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I have enough money to buy the new super yacht which costs millions and whenever I open up my phone and go to Internet I never see the advert for the new super galaxy yacht which you can customize.  Even when I go on dock tease I can't see it. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You can also navigate through the internet in GTA 5 with the browser bar.
Go to your phone and then click on the browser bar on the top and type in:
**www.docktease.com/yacht** you should be navigated to the site where you can start customizing your yacht.

Comment: No you can not there is no "/" in the typing menu